# Efficient pandas grouby + nunique rolling calculation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I am trying to build a scalable method to calculate the number of unique members that have modified a certain file up to and including the latest modified_date. The `unique_member_until_now` column contains expected result for each file.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

# Example Dataset

df = pd.DataFrame({'File': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
 'Member': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X'],
 'modified_date': [Timestamp('2021-11-25 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-11-28 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-12-14 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-17 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-11-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-11-16 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-12-16 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-12-29 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-30 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-11-23 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2021-12-17 00:00:00')],
 'unique_member_until_now': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2]})
```

[image]

`df.groupby("File")["Member"].transform('nunique')` ofcourse doesn't give the intended result

The current approach is to iterate over every group and each record in the group, but I am sure that is grossly inefficient and slow when dealing with millions for rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient method would be to compute the (non) [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) on the File+Member columns, then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) File and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
(~df[['File', 'Member']].duplicated()).groupby(df['File']).cumsum()
```

Saving as column:

```
df['unique_member_until_now'] = (~df[['File', 'Member']].duplicated()).groupby(df['File']).cumsum()
```

output:

```
   File Member modified_date  unique_member_until_now
0     A      X    2021-11-25                        1
1     A      X    2021-11-28                        1
2     A      Y    2021-12-14                        2
3     B      X    2021-10-17                        1
4     B      Y    2021-11-01                        2
5     B      Y    2021-11-04                        2
6     B      X    2021-11-16                        2
7     B      Z    2021-12-16                        3
8     B      Y    2021-12-29                        3
9     C      X    2021-10-30                        1
10    C      Y    2021-11-23                        2
11    C      X    2021-12-17                        2
```

Comment: Nice...because this avoids `apply` ;)

Comment: @richardec I just ran some tests and it's 1.5-2x faster than apply, you had the correct logic though (+1) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `File`, and then use [`is_duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.is_duplicated.html) (inverted with `~`) + [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df['unique_member_until_now'] = df.groupby('File').apply(lambda g: (~g['Member'].duplicated()).cumsum()).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   File Member modified_date  unique_member_until_now
0     A      X    2021-11-25                        1
1     A      X    2021-11-28                        1
2     A      Y    2021-12-14                        2
3     B      X    2021-10-17                        1
4     B      Y    2021-11-01                        2
5     B      Y    2021-11-04                        2
6     B      X    2021-11-16                        2
7     B      Z    2021-12-16                        3
8     B      Y    2021-12-29                        3
9     C      X    2021-10-30                        1
10    C      Y    2021-11-23                        2
11    C      X    2021-12-17                        2
```